# gmock unit test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, googletest, googlemock

Consider this situation

```
class A
{
   A(){}
   virtual int Method1(){return 0;}
};

class B
{
   static int Method2(){ return a.Method1();}
   A a;
};
```

I need to test class B, so I want to use mocked Method1 to replace real Method1 but not changing class B's code. variable a of class B is neither pointer nor reference, so is there any ways or walk-around to solve this problem.

Comment: Why can you not make "a" into a pointer?

Comment: ^ what he said. You need to create the mock object _outside_ of your class and then inject it (via ctor or B::setA()).